# Error in connecting with mysql using android

Tags: android, mysql

I'm developing an app which will retrieve some data from mysql database. I needed to connect my app with mysql directly to do this. I know, that i have to use an ip address instead of localhost in getconnection method. here is the code :

```
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Log.i("output","class");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.1:3306/outsidelaundry", "root", "");
        Log.i("output","connection");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        String query = "select Name from nonmember";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);        
        while(rs.next())
        {
            val = val + rs.getString(1) + "\n";
        }
        Log.i("output",val);
        con.close();
```

Manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

To be honest i don't know what is the ip address i want to use to get connection with mysql database. Above i used ip address is not working too. Please help me with this.

Comment: Can you upload the code of your AndroidManifest.xml ? and is your device running on Wifi ? because as you are connecting your my sql with local IP your device must be connected to your local network by Wifi.

Comment: I couldn't able to put all code of manifest.xml..No I'm not using wifi

Comment: As I explained you must use Wifi otherwise you can not access mysql locally. And you need to put Wifi Permission in AndroidManifest.xml as well.

Comment: "ping" the IP address from your command prompt.

Comment: you cannot connect directly to a mysql database with android, you have to use other means to get the data, an easy way is to use php scripts to that query the db and return a json with the data which the app will work with... look at the following tutorial: http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/connecting-mysql-database

Comment: But i'm connecting with internet.. and above mentioned ip address is correct?

Answer (score 0):

you cannot connect directly to a mysql database with android, you have to use other means to get the data, an easy way is to use php scripts to that query the db and return a JSON with the data which you can then convert into useable data for the app.

look at the following tutorial: [helloandroid.com/tutorials/connecting-mysql-database](http://helloandroid.com/tutorials/connecting-mysql-database)